# How should zend-route and zend-router tag be handled

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

I was checking out [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) tag for edit wiki. Then i found another tag [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) which is extensively used for zend routing related questions. Now I am confused if they are synonyms tag. When I checked questions count I got following figures.

- [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) have 71 questions.
- [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) have 290 questions.
- 50 questions have both [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) and [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route).

So they both are used for routing related questions. So if both are same then we need to apply synonyms. While if both are different we need to edit wiki. In later case how can we distinguish [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) it from [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) .

I personally think that we can edit details about [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) which is [zend routing component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) while keep [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) for general ZF2 routing related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) have a usage guidance:

> Routing in Zend Framework's MVC implementation. Zend Framework is an open source, object-oriented web application framework implemented in PHP 5 and licensed under the New BSD License.

Now this guidance doesn't say anything particularly about ZF1 or ZF2.

But the tag [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) doesn't have any usage guidance so it can either be added as a synonym zend [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) or it can be defined as the ZF2 specific tag.

Comment: Why should there be a ZF2-specific tag for it?