# Merge [zend-route] and [zend-router] as synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

From the tag wiki of [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) and [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route), you'll see that these are pretty much the same.

Current stats:

- [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) have 76 questions.
- [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route) have 326 questions.

I believe either [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) should be made synonym of [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route). 
Or all [zend-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-router) should be retaged to [zend-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-route).

Related: [How should zend-route and zend-router tag be handled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289872/how-should-zend-route-and-zend-router-tag-be-handled)